# Can I configure DMVPN on Cisco Packet Tracer 6.0.1?

Tags: cisco

I tried to configure a DMVPN between two routers (hub and spoke) on Cisco Packet Tracer 6.0.1, but it does not accept the commands, i.e., when I type `tunnel mode gre multipoint`, I get an error on `multipoint` as it does not exist as an option. Does the program support DMVPNs or should I try GNS3?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packet Tracer is a tool for basic network simulation (actually specifically designed for CCNA preparation). And simulation is the key word in this sentence: It only simulates an IOS router, and it lacks a fairly broad set of features, including but not limited to:

- Limited feature set regarding routing protocols (route summarization in OSPF, tweaking of some EIGRP settings such as hold time, partial support for frame relay...)
- No NAT Exception on the simulated ASA
- Missing many crypto features
- No suppport for multipoint GRE tunnels
- No support for DMVPN at all

After all, its for CCNA-level study. So the short answer is: No you cannot. You could use GNS3 or Cisco VIRL to experiment with that topic.

Answer (score -2):

Look at this little example:

```
conf t
int tunnel 0
tunnel source fa0/0
tunnel mode gre multipoint
```

Comment: You should expand you answer. Why does this solve the problem since the last line is what the OP says is an invalid option?

Comment: `tunnel mode gre multipoint` works only on tunnel interface, if you just type where you want this won't work.

Comment: and use GNS3 it will be works 100%

Comment: If you read the question, it says that `multipoint` is not an option. In any case, your answer is of low quality since you don't explain anything. You should edit it to include an explanation, and quote and provide links to your sources if you have some.

Comment: You could improve your answer by editing it to add more details to make it more useful both for the original poster and future users. Typically short answers like this could provide reasoning why you believe this is the answer, more explanation about the concepts mentioned, references/links to supporting resources, or applicable examples.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the really late reply.

Comment: @ga88er: yes, I applied these commands to a tunnel interface and the program doesn't accept them. Anyway, after reading a lot of resources online, it turned out CPT almost certainly doesn't support DMVPNs, since it is mainly a program to prepare for CCNA-level questions and lacks advanced functionality (DMVPNs, it turns out, are CCIE-level material). So I am using GNS3 for this purpose.